# JMenuBar is not visible

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I have the following function which sets up the GUI.

```
public void go() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simplex RP Client V1.1 Beta");
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    outgoing = new JTextField(50);






//      rpMode = new JComboBox("OOC", "IC", "IT", "ME");
    charName = new JTextField(30);
    charName.setText("Character Name");
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
    outgoing.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
    mainPanel.add(qScroller);
    mainPanel.add(outgoing);
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);
    mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, charName);
//  setUpNetworking();
    Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    readerThread.start();

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem connect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
    file.add(connect);


        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, menubar);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(577,375);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
} // close go
```

I can't seem to get my JMenuBar to show up. I've been trying to fix it for a few hours now, I'm new to Java. Any help would be much appreciated. I don't really have a whole lot to say, I'm sure it's a simple problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never add your JMenu to your JMenuBar: `menuBar.add(file);`

Comment: It worked, however there is a horrible looking space at the top of my program. I clearly also messed up somewhere, a second time. http://i.imgur.com/uPZ6Q.png

Comment: Oh I found it, was a silly mistake on my part. I had this in my code when I was trying to get the menubar to show. `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, menubar);`